# Watin with C# how catch a WatiN TimeOutException

Tags: c#, exception, watin, timeoutexception

I am runing Watin dll in a C# script that opens and close  browser with a long list of  url

```
using (var browser = new IE(url))
{
 //do stuffs
 browser.Close();
}
```

most of the time it works without erros but sometime Watin throw a 'WatiN.Core.Exceptions.TimeoutException'

It looks that exception canot be catch like classics exception by a classix try catch

```
try
{
 using (var browser = new IE(url))
  {
   //do stuffs
   browser.Close();         
  }
}

catch (Exception e)
{
//never go in
}
```

Around 1 time in 100 , watin fails to open link, and instead going in Exception, it stop script and throw me an Exception with boring message : 
An unhandled exception of type 'WatiN.Core.Exceptions.TimeoutException' occurred in WatiN.Core.dll

Do you know how to catch this Exception or how to prevent it?

Comment: Actually, without showing the actual things you are doing (i.e. the `//do stuffs` content), I do not think you will get a qualified answer.

Comment: Have you tried: Catch WatiN.Core.Exceptions.TimeoutException ?

Comment: Maybe the website is the problem? Maybe it has sort of bot protection or something like that?